# How to set environment variables in CMake so that they can be visible at build time?

Tags: c++, unix, cmake, environment-variables, cmake-language

On macOS 12, I tried to set some environment variables in `CMakeLists.txt` file like this.

```
# Add environment variables
set(ENV{VK_ICD_FILENAMES} /Users/username/VulkanSDK/macOS/share/vulkan/icd.d/MoltenVK_icd.json)
set(ENV{VK_LAYER_PATH} /Users/username/VulkanSDK/macOS/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d)
```

But I quickly realize those environment variables only affects the current CMake instance. Basically, if I use `message()` in the same `CMakeLists.txt` file, CMake can print out the exact same value as I set. However, during build time, those variables do not exist and can't guide build phase.

My current solution is to generate Xcode project file and add those environment variables manually in `Edit Scheme`. But I want to learn CMake and do all the configurations in CMake. My question is if there is any way I can set environment variables in `CMakeLists.txt` file so that they at least persist during build phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you want is `CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_<an-attribute>`

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_an-attribute.html